# Neo4j Cypher not fulfilling query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a newbie of Neo4j and I'm working with a database provided by the examples ([Link)](https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/).
I'm trying to create a new relatioship between each actor that acted in the same movie and I run this query

`MATCH (p1:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(p2:Actor)
WHERE id(p1)>id(p2)
MERGE (p1)-[:ACTED_WITH]->(p2)`

But for an unknown reason it creates just some relationships but not others. I've checked both the Node types and the Relationships types but seems that they are all the same, so the query should run correctly in all cases.

If you want to try this thing just download the DB from the link, run the query above, and check this two movies, with Avatar works but not worked with Hart's War

`MATCH p=(a)-[]-()
WHERE a.title = "Hart's War" OR a.title="Avatar"
RETURN p`

Comment: Unfortunately that db hasn't been updated to work with the later versions of Neo4j, you'd have to migrate the data, though I'm not sure if that explains the behavior you're seeing, however. Have you tried using the built-in movies database by using `:play movies`?

Comment: @InverseFalcon you just need to add `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` to the configuration file of neo4j and he'll migrate the format for you!

Comment: Tried with the db you linked, your query works just fine, all coactors seem connected properly. Which version of Neo4j are you using, and do you have auto-complete on in your graph results?

Comment: I'm using neo4j 3.2.1 on Windows. Can you please try on that database, after executing my query, to check if also the movie "Hart's War" is correctly connected?
About the auto-complete, I have no idea, I just installed neo4j with the default settings. I'll check!

Comment: I'm able to replicate the problem with community version 3.2.1 on Mac. I'll see if I can give it a closer look soon.

Comment: Any news? I've tried with older version of Neo4j and just works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do what you need:

```
MATCH (p1:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)
MATCH (p2:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m)
WHERE p2 <> p1
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[r:ACTED_WITH]-(p2)
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN r IS NULL THEN [0] ELSE [] END) |
    MERGE (p1)-[:ACTED_WITH]->(p2)  
)
```

I do not know if this way is the best to do this, but I believe this works.

To create the `:ACTED_WITH` relationship only once between two nodes (and not `(a)-[:ACTED_WHT]->(b)` and `(a)<-[:ACTED_WHT]-(b)`) I'm using [this trick](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/06/17/neo4j-load-csv-handling-conditionals/). Basicaly I'm simulating an `IF` condition using `FOREACH` and `CASE` statements.

Tested with Neo4j 3.2.

[image: Output]

Comment: I've tried running your query, same result as mine but it creates also the reverse link (`(a)-[:ACTED_WHT]->(b) and (a)<-[:ACTED_WHT]-(b)`)

My problem is that the relationship it is not created along all graph but just on a subset of it

Comment: Weird. Worked here with Neo4j 3.2 and the Movie Database Dataset. I updated my answer with a printscreen. Note that I adapted the relationship types and  labels.

Comment: Just downloaded again the dataset, runned only your query. The only movie i could find with Clint Eastwood and Richard Harris is "Unforgiven", and this is a screenshot of how it shows on my computer.
http://imgur.com/a/6U0ht

Comment: What Neo4j are you using and what database version are you downloading?

Comment: I'm using neo4j 3.2.1 for Windows, Community Edition. [Dataset](http://example-data.neo4j.org/files/cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors_2.1.6.zip)
 I've converted the database for the newest version of neo enabling this property in the configuration `dbms.allow_format_migration=true`